# Tweak Any Errors with Docker Build for Maven-3.6.3 and Java SDK 8 Application

Tags: java, docker, maven, docker-compose, dockerfile

New to the java community, and would appreciate all of the help that I can get with my Dockerfile and Docker Compose setup.

These are the requirements of my project.

- Use Maven 3.6.3 and Java 8 SDK,
- create a workdir named /app
- create a non root user with root permissions (max -777)
- install basic linux tools and utilities
- change to the root folder as a root user and cd into .m2/settings.xml and edit it with the code below.

Additionally, I need to copy over the pom.xml, the /target, the /src, and settings.xml and the app dir itself as illustrated in my attempt below.

And then run and execute this entire application as a non-root user with root permissions to create, delete, and update files and dirs in the root dir and throughout /app for the build with mvn.

```
# Custom image from Maven on DockerHub
# Language: dockerfile
FROM maven:3.6.3-amazoncorretto-8

# Set the working dir
WORKDIR /app

# Create a non root user
ARG USERNAME=jefferson
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

# Add linux dependenciesq
RUN yum install wget -y
RUN yum install shadow-utils -y

# Create the user
RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME \
    && yum install sudo -y \
    && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    && chmod 777 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    && sudo groupadd docker \
    && sudo usermod -aG docker $USERNAME \
    && newgrp docker 

# Change to the root folder and edit the settings.xml for Maven
WORKDIR /root/.m2
RUN rm -rf settings.xml
RUN echo '<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" \
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" \
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 \
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd"> \
</settings>' >> settings.xml

WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./

USER $USERNAME

# Run the application
CMD ["mvn", "clean", "verify", "-Pcargo.run", "-X"]
```

```
version: '1.0'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: sh -c "mvn clean verify && mvn -Pcargo.run -X"
    ports:
      - 3100:3100
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
     # give absolute path of the workdir app working_dir
      - .:/app
    # give the absolute bath of src starting at app
      - ./src:/app/src
    # give the absolute path of target
      - ./target:/app/target
    # give the absolute path of the maven repo
      - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
    # give thepom.xml
      - ./pom.xml:/app/pom.xml
```

That being said the `docker compose up` command should both build and run the container on port 3100. Can somebody give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: If anyone is curious, here are the docs: https://hub.docker.com/_/maven

Comment: You are asking for a full tutorial here. I suggest you read this: https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-stage-builds/ and then maybe search the web for `java maven multistage build` but don't just copy-paste code. try to undeerstand it. then you can come back here with specific questions for a certain command/step.

Comment: @Mihai I have done every single task listed to form and do devops for a living, I know what specific questions I am asking and it is geared towards working with root files with a maven setup which requires you to run an application as a non root user, this is a very specific question

Comment: Do you usually install `sudo` in docker containers? I thought you only want to run the app as another user for security reason. Then why give that user super powers? And do you usually give full access to files: `chmod 777 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME`? Why do you declare CMD in Dockerfile to then just overwrite in docker-compose? If you build with Maven in docker why still map `./target` as a volume? Run the above and you will need `sudo` on host to even do `mvn clean`since your target folder's files will be owned by some strange uid 1000. I also do devops...